# Providing a RESTful service with ASP.NET MVC for AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, rest, angularjs-resource

I'm using the $resource object in AngularJS. Since it has a single URL for all REST calls, what should I provide on the ASP.NET MVC server side for each of the inbuilt calls (get, delete etc.)?
$resource.get and $resource.delete will both call something like /app/customer/8 so how do I distinguish between these calls in my MVC controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use MVC. Use WebApi. Create a new WebApi project and look at the `ValuesController` to understand how.